# How can I retrieve query string from my webpage .ASPX to my HTML file script?

Tags: c#, javascript, html

Here is my Code in my page 'Welcome.aspx.cs':

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string menus = string.Empty;
   if (this.hfAccessLvl.Value == string.Empty)
   {
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
   }          
   myMenu.Text = AlMenu("js/MyMenu.html?accesLevel=" + this.hfAccessLvl.Value + "|" + virtualDrive, "no", "400px", "100");
}
```

In my MyMenu.html code:

```
<html>
<body runat="server">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <head runat="server">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;CHARSET=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Test Only</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="crossbrowser.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="outlook.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">                        
              var o = new createOutlookBar('Bar',0,0,screenSize.width,screenSize.height,'#606060','white')
              var p
              var accessLevell = GetQueryString('accesLevel').split('|')[0]; // Get Access level of user
              var virtualDrive = GetQueryString('accesLevel').split('|')[1];  // Get Virtual drive that was set if any...
              //create first panel
              p = new createPanel('al','Nestle Web Sites');
              p.addButton('home.gif','Home','parent.location="' + virtualDrive + '/Welcome.aspx"');
              p.addButton('home.gif','Log-Out','parent.location="' + virtualDrive + '/Login.aspx"');
              o.addPanel(p);            
              o.draw();        
        </script>
    </head>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to get the query string value that I'd pass from Welcome.aspx.cs in my MyMenu.html script file:

```
var accessLevell = GetQueryString('accesLevel').split('|')[0]; 
var virtualDrive = GetQueryString('accesLevel').split('|')[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function GetQueryString( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
```

(code taken from http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html )

Comment: Hello, Thank for your answer.  I tested it and found correct.